# my simple user account has no permit to restore previous session or closed tabs on Firefox

Tags: firefox, browser, browser-history, limited-user

I would like to use limited account funcionality like to restore what I have closed but I think there is something wrong with it: I just can find the ordinary cronology where I can remember to solve the matter.
I am using firefox 12 on windows Xp.
Please, 
Paolo

Answer (score 0):

I have found problem happening because of an extension that I do not use as admininistrator: so I arranged finally to disable that and it seems to work well actually.